# How to pass data to another doctype

Tags: erpnext, frappe

I have 2 doctypes, When i press button i want to send fields `data`, and `items` to another doctype, during research i found sample like this. But doesn't working at all. Any suggestion?

```
frappe.ui.form.on('Testdatafrom', {
    custom_button: function (frm, cdt, cdn) {
        msgprint(frm.doc.custom_label);
        frappe.set_route("Form", "Testdatato", "New Testdatato 1", { "name": frm.doc.custom_label});
    }
});
```

[image]

And show `custom_label` in here like this

```
frappe.ui.form.on('Testdatato', {
    onload(frm) {
        frm.set_value('custom_label', name);
    }
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
frappe.ui.form.on('Testdatato', {
    onload(frm) {
        let name = frappe.route_options.name;
        frm.set_value('custom_label', name);
    }
});
```

The object passed along with the route are saved under `frappe.route_options`